# Is there currently an issue calling direct methods from Azure portal?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

For a simple test, I created a Linux device following the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux).

I then tried to call the "reset" direct method through the Azure portal tempSensor module. I received the following error:

```
Failed to invoke device method: {"message":"Device {\"Message\":\"{\\\"errorCode\\\":404103,\\\"trackingId\\\":\\\"cc24992d14d44a498e65d1430907066c-G:2-TimeStamp:07/17/2018 16:52:44\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Timed out waiting for device to connect.\\\",\\\"info\\\":{\\\"timeout\\\":\\\"00:00:10\\\"},\\\"timestampUtc\\\":\\\"2018-07-17T16:52:44.3400692Z\\\"}\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"\"} not registered"}
```

The device was connected and sending data to IoT Hub.

I then created a second device with proprietary code and am also unable to get a direct method working to a module.

Some things I am not sure about that could provide an answer:

1. Is there a route needed from $upstream to the module accepting a direct method?
2. Is there an issue in the portal calling direct methods to modules?
3. Is the following code still a valid way to call a direct method on a module?

   var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
   var writeMessageMethod = new CloudToDeviceMethod("command");
   serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync(deviceId, moduleId, writeMessageMethod).Wait();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently,

> invoking direct methods using a module ID is supported in the [C#
>   preview SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.16.0-preview-004). For this purpose, use the
>   ServiceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync() method and pass in the
>   deviceId and moduleId as parameters.

Reference "[Method invocation for IoT Edge modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods#method-invocation-for-iot-edge-modules)"

So from Azure Portal seems not supported.

> Is there a route needed from $upstream to the module accepting a
>   direct method?

No need.

> Is there an issue in the portal calling direct methods to modules?

You need to call the direct method from a module and use C# preview SDK mentioned above. So from portal seems not supported yet.

> Is the following code still a valid way to call a direct method on a
>   module?

```
var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString); 
var writeMessageMethod = new CloudToDeviceMethod("command");     
serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync(deviceId, moduleId, writeMessageMethod).Wait();
```

Yes, the code is right. But note, if you name your direct method to "command", you need call "command" instead of "reset".

Reference "[Azure IoT Edge V2 - Direct Method Invocation Sample (Linux only for now)](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/tree/master/v2/samples/direct_method_invocation_sample#azure-iot-edge-v2---direct-method-invocation-sample-linux-only-for-now)".